# Block local (unix) users from sending mail

Tags: email, postfix, account-restrictions, mail-command

Is there a way to block a local/unix user (or a list of local users) from sending mails via `mail` command (or maybe even in postfix, which is the MTA I have).

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [Postfix restriction classes](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html#external).

Comment: @KarolBabioch Ok, I did the following and yet I'm still able to send with the local unix user "gitolite": http://pastebin.com/bN46U7mr I also restarted postfix. What is wrong?

Comment: @KarolBabioch btw, just realized that there is a missing comma after the ```hash:<path>``` line. I fixed that but it's still not working. And by "not working" I mean I can "su gitolite" and then "mail -s Test foo@bar.com" and the mail gets to the queue.

Comment: Can you paste the loglines generated by postfix after the `mail` command is run?

Comment: Ah, your comment actually lead me to the solution :) I forgot to generate the .db file with postmap. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by @Gilles, I'm leaving here what I did so others can benefit from it.

My machine's host is `abcxyz.ovh.net` and the user I was trying to block was `foobar`.

I ended up creating `/etc/postfix/sender_access` with the following content:

```
foobar@abcxyz.ovh.net REJECT
```

Then I compiled it with `postmap /etc/postfix/sender_access`.

Finally, I added this to my Postfix configuration:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_access,
 ...,
 ...,
 ...,
 ...
```

Comment: It works for local users, but it doesn't work for users sending mail connecting `localhost:25`.